# Max CaretPosition in JTextPane unequal to Textlength with CRLF Linebreak

Tags: java, swing, newline, jeditorpane

A JEditorPane has a strange behaviour concerning the CaretPosition after a Linebreak and the TextLength. If there is a CarriageReturn and a LineFeed, the Caret Position after that break is one to low, because Java is considering it as one character in calculating the CaretPosition. The Textlength however handles it correct as two characters. This behavior seems to result from the [DefaultEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html), but I don’t see a possibility to get .getCaretPosition synchronous to .getText().length() independent of the used linebreak.

I have attached a small Code. Just place the Caret at the end of the second line and press update. The TextLength is 5, but the CaretPosition is only 4 at the end. If I use only a CR as a linebreak it is ok. A JTextArea is doing it right. The origin of the problem is similiar to   [Caret position in JTextPane is not correct ?! Bug or expected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878392/caret-position-in-jtextpane-is-not-correct-bug-or-expected-behavior).

Do you have any ideas to solve that?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.text.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class test2 extends JFrame {

    JTextComponent testingArea = new JEditorPane();
    JButton button = new JButton("Update");
    JTextComponent resultArea = new JTextField(25);


    public test2() {
    initialise();
    testingArea.setText("01\r\n4");
}


private void initialise() {
    testingArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(testingArea);
    getContentPane().add(new JLabel("answer"));
    getContentPane().add(resultArea);
    getContentPane().add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try { 
                int caretPosition = testingArea.getCaretPosition();
                int textLength = testingArea.getText().length();
                resultArea.setText("TextLength is " + textLength + ". Current CaretPosition is " + caretPosition);
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                resultArea.setText("ERROR");
            }

        }
    });
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final test2 ex = new test2();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ex.pack();
            ex.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Does it matter?  Is it affecting anything you are doing??

Comment: I need the correct getCaretPosition for defining a substring of the Text dynamically and to show the correct current caret Position depending on the text in the model.

Comment: The solution is shown in the thread that you linked to. You need to get the text from the Document, NOT the component. Maybe reading http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/ will help you understand what is happening. Also, you probably shouldn't be using a JEditorPane. It was designed to display HTML. Use either a JTextArea or JTextPane.